# Accessing C# DataObject data part from javascript

Tags: javascript, c#

Is it possible to access the C# DataObject data from javascript?

```
DataObject data = new DataObject();
data.SetText(stringBuilder.ToString());
data.SetData("application/json", itemsJson);

Clipboard.Clear();
Clipboard.SetDataObject(data);

var x = Clipboard.GetData("application/json");
```

In the C# side, `x` will be the json string. But it lost at `js` side.

**EDIT**

With

```
text = ev.clipboardData.getData("text/plain");
```

I've got the text, but:

```
var json = ev.clipboardData.getData("application/json");
```

nothing will be in `json`.

**UPDATE**

As I see, I can not access the data part of the dataobject from javascript. I think this is for some security reason, but not sure.

Comment: Which framework are you using? and I think `Clipboard` works with `Windows.Forms`

Comment: @Satpal This is a native windows program. When I user wants to add a comment, I am opening a new window with a `ChromiumWebBrowser` component. This method is a copy to clipboard method, and on paste I'd like to read out the jsonstring. I can not change the C# method.

Comment: For security reasons, JavaScript (in a browser) cannot directly access the clipboard unless its triggered by a user action (e.g. a click).  Test this out by putting a button on your page and access the clipboard from within that buttons click handler.

Comment: @Amy click event has no clipboard property :)

Comment: No, that's not what I said.  You don't access the clipboard from the click event object.  You access the clipboard *inside the click event handler*.  Use your existing code *inside* the handler.